# C++ Is it possible to create a private link between objects?

Tags: c++, linked-list

As far as I can understand, linked list can only implemented with an outsider class. Because a class can't have a member varable of it's own type and a node list need that type. The problem is, if the link is intented to be used by a specific class. If, the link class created outside, it will be available to be created as a standalone object.

It's okay if the link class/struct is a pure link object because it can be used for linking another object type.  But, in case I need a link that has a functionallity that only related to a certain object, the public availability of it will be pointless. And I think it's better to be created as a private.

Let's take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/LACRko23/) declaration:

```
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Node
{
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const T& item, Node<T>* ptrnext = NULL);
        T data;
        // access to the next node
        Node<T>* NextNode();
        // list modification methods
        void InsertAfter(Node<T>* p);
        Node<T>* DeleteAfter();
        Node<T> * GetNode(const T& item, Node<T>* nextptr = NULL);
    private:

        Node<T> * next;
        unordered_map<string, T*> nodeList;
};
```

The `unordred_map<string,T*>` member can only have meaning with a certain object. So, it will be pointless for `Node` class to be available outside.

Is it possible? Or maybe is it a bad idea to add a non-generic funtionallity for link class?

Comment: I think the better question is what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you implementing your own linked list, and at the same time, using an STL container such as `unordered_map`?  Why not go all the way and use `std::list` also?

Comment: "Because a class can't have a member varable of it's own type and a node list need that type."  Well, okay, but a class can have a member pointer of its own type.  This is a very common way to set up linked lists.

Comment: @NathanOliver I try to create a tree like connection between object. But not binary tree which only has two child. The `unordeded_map` will hold pointers of some childrens.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
  A* m_pnext = nullptr;
public:
  inline A* next() { return m_pnext; }
  inline void set_next(A*ptr) { m_pnext = ptr; }
}

template <class type>
class LinkedList {
  type *m_pfirst = nullptr;
public:
  void add(type * ptr) {
    if ( nullptr == m_pfirst ) {
      m_pfirst = ptr;
    } else {
      type * n = m_pfirst, p = m_pfirst->next;
      while (nullptr != p) {
        n = p;
        p = n->next();
      }
      n->set_next(ptr);
    }
  }
};
```

Plenty of room for improvement, of course. I'll let you exercise your mind.

Comment: It's best to explain your answer instead of just typing in a block of code.